# What is the preferred way to write functions in JavaScript AMD?

Tags: javascript, function, module, amd

I'm currently working with SuiteScript 2.0 and seeing that this particular API uses AMD, I'm confused on how to write functions. I've seen examples do this:

```
 define([], function(){
 function doSomething(objParams){
   // do something
 }

  return {
     foo : doSomething
  }
 });
```

Whereas there are examples that go with this style:

```
define([], function(){
var Endpoint = {};

EndPoint.foo = function(params){
//do Something
};

return Endpoint;

});
```

I'm quite confused on how we should be writing main and helper functions in AMD so I'd like to know if there's a specific standard that's ES compliant.

Comment: The first example is invalid JS. What's confusing you?

Comment: Have a read of this, it should help - https://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/

Comment: @evolutionxbox I've used both the 1st and 2nd example. In SuiteScript 2.0, you need to return a function (and it should be named, not anonymous), depending on the script type. So if I was calling a specific event type, say pageInit, I need to do that in the return statement. I'm not sure how the 1st example is invalid JS, but I'll look further into it and maybe I missed something. EDIT: Saw the issue. I'll fix it now. Thanks!